# Should I autorelease before return form -(NSString*)description?

Tags: objective-c

Today i was overwriting -(NSString*)description method and i wondered if need to autorelease this string before returning it.

```
-(NSString*)description {
    NSMutableString *response = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    // perform appends
    return [response autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, as per ownership rule your function must not delegate the ownership of the returned string to the caller.

Comment: You can also avoid the autorelease by instantiating your mutable string with `[NSMutableString string]`. Same effect as the autorelease, but looks cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Any method whose name does not begin with `alloc`, `new`, `copy`, or `mutableCopy` should not return a retained object. See [Memory Managment Rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html)